# How to remove space between pages of PageView in flutter

Tags: listview, zooming, flutter-layout, pageviews

I am making a list like the image below. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBPny.jpg)

I followed the instructions in the link :[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@tonyowen/flutter-pageview-zoom-transition-98c380632b2d)

I want to display as many items as possible while the middle page remains the same size. 
So is there a way to remove spaces between pages? I use a PageView to display the list. I tried everything but it didn't work like the picture below. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdrFy.png)

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'dart:math';

  const SCALE_FRACTION = 0.15; //small circle 0.15
  const FULL_SCALE = 0.5; //0.5
  const PAGER_HEIGHT = 200.0;

  class ItCrowdPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _ItCrowdPageState createState() => _ItCrowdPageState();
  }

  class _ItCrowdPageState extends State<ItCrowdPage> {
    double viewPortFraction = 1/5;

    PageController pageController;

    int currentPage = 4;

    List<Map<String, String>> listOfCharacters = [
      {'image': "#140125", 'name': "Richmond"},
      {'image': "#FF01FF",'name': "Roy"},
      {'image': "#CC99AA", 'name': "Moss"},
      {'image': "#AACCCC", 'name': "Douglas"},
      {'image': "#775522", 'name': "Jen"},
      {'image': "#331144", 'name': "Moss 1"},
      {'image': "#991245", 'name': "Moss 2"},
      {'image': "#784511", 'name': "Moss 3"},
      {'image': "#CA15AA", 'name': "Moss 4"},

    ];

    double page = 4.0;

    @override
    void initState() {
      pageController =
          PageController(initialPage: currentPage, viewportFraction: viewPortFraction);
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 1,
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
          title: Text(
            "The IT Crowd",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Container(
              height: PAGER_HEIGHT,

              child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
                  if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                    setState(() {
                      page = pageController.page;
                    });

                  }
                  return true;
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: page == currentPage ? 200 : 50,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.2),
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      pageSnapping: true,
                      onPageChanged: (pos) {
                        setState(() {
                          currentPage = pos;
                        });
                      },
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: pageController,
                      itemCount: listOfCharacters.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final scale =
                        max(SCALE_FRACTION, (FULL_SCALE - (index - page).abs()) + viewPortFraction);
                        return circleOffer(
                            listOfCharacters[index]['image'], scale, index);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                listOfCharacters[currentPage]['name'],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget circleOffer(String color, double scale, int index) {
      color = color.replaceAll('#', '0xff');
      double sizeCircleSmall = page == index ? 50 * (scale * 1) : 30 * (scale);

      return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          height: PAGER_HEIGHT * scale,
          width: PAGER_HEIGHT * scale,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Color(int.parse(color)),
                ),
              ),
              new Align (
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: new Container(
                  width: sizeCircleSmall,
                  height: sizeCircleSmall,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.white),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new Text("A",
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: How you found answer for this ? I'm also looking for same what you have mentioned in question. Could you please help me ?

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar  Sorry for the late response. You can refer to this demo code:  https://github.com/Shokichi1997/swiper_custom.git

Comment: Thank you!! but in this example i'm not able to customise it.. I need some rounded images